# Type 'Any' Has no Subscript Members in xcode 8 Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, xcode8

My App is supposed to go to a specific location to pull down the website it needs to load. In 2.3 it worked like a charm, but since I've updated xcode (which I don't have a ton of experience in) it is giving me the error "type 'Any' has no subscript members" and highlighting the "json" right before line three

```
...Retriever = json["WEB"]...
```

this is the code related to it.

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments)

      if let Retriever = json["WEB"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                 for website in Retriever {

                    if let name = website["URL"] as? String {

                          self.loadAddressURL(name)
```

I feel like I am missing something small. If there is a better way to do this, I would love suggestions. The URL returns this JSON

```
{
  "WEB" : [
           {
            "URL" : "http://www.google.com"
           }    
          ]
}
```

but I would love it if I could simplify it to just

```
{"URL":"http://www.google.com"}
```

Answer (score 65):

**Try this:**

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
```

**Safe way:**

```
do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {
        print(json)
    }
} catch let err{
    print(err.localizedDescription)
}
```

You have to cast type `Any` to Swift dictionary type `[String:AnyObject]`.

**Edit: Swift 3**
In swift 3 the purpose of `AnyObject` is more clarified. So more favourable Swift Dictionary type will be `[String:Any]`.

**`Any`** is an alias for any data type.
**`AnyObject`** is an alias for any data type derived from a class.

For more info visit: *https://craiggrummitt.com/2016/09/16/any-vs-anyobject-vs-nsobject-in-swift-3/*

Comment: Worked like a charm, I had to add the "!" after the as but it worked like a charm

Comment: Thanks a lot :* You saved me hours of headscratching

Comment: It will be good if someone can add more relative valuable information to this answer as it is becoming popular. :)