# Type 'Any?' has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk, swift3

I am trying to retrieve email id after fb login in my app. However I am getting an error when i try to get the value from result.

The error is:`Type 'Any?' has no subscript members`.

```
func fetchProfile()
{
    print("Fetch Profile")
    let parameters = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name,  picture.type(large)"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).start { (connection, result, error) in

        let email = result["email"] as? String  //Type 'Any?' has no subscript members error occurs here.
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516199/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-in-xcode-8-swift-3/39516303#39516303

Answer (score 12, accepted):

change this

```
 let email = result["email"] as? String
```

into

```
  guard let resultNew = result as? [String:Any] 

 let email = resultNew["email"]  as! String
```

**full answer**

```
let parameters = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name,  picture.type(large)"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).start { (connection, result, error) in

        guard let resultNew = result as? [String:Any] 

       let email = resultNew["email"]  as! String
    }
```

Comment: Xcode is suggestion to change the following line 
    let email = resultNew["email"]
to
    let email = resultNew?["email"]

And the value in email is nil after doing so.

Comment: @Vyshakh - which line

Comment: Updated comment

Comment: what the result you get here `resultNew`

Comment: I am getting nil for that also

Comment: @Vyshakh - in ths place use [String:[Any]] or use this [String:Any]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123847/discussion-between-vyshakh-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 10):

**For Swift 3**.

change this-->

```
let email = result["email"] as? String
```

Into -->

```
if let fbemail = (result as AnyObject)["email"]! as? String
{
   print(fbemail)
}
```

Comment: @Fogmeister, that didn't work for me, so i posted my answer  because it may help some one, posting an answer doesn't harm anyone, they're is no point giving a down mark, through out stackoverflow you'll find many answers rather than the accepted one. what is your problem giving a downmark.?