# Facebook SDK error for subscript members

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using Facebook SDK for login and fetching data at my end but unable to solve the issue I am facing challenges related to syntax

```
func fetchProfile() {
    let parameters = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).start(completionHandler: { (connection, user, requestError) -> Void in

        if requestError != nil {
            print(requestError)
            return
        }

        var email = user["email"] as? String
        let firstName = user["first_name"] as? String
        let lastName = user["last_name"] as? String

        self.nameLabel.text = "\(firstName!) \(lastName!)"

        var pictureUrl = ""

        if let picture = user["picture"] as? NSDictionary, let data = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary, let url = data["url"] as? String {
            pictureUrl = url
        }

    })
}
```

In the line `var email = user["email"] as ? String` i getting error as type any? has no transcript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516199/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-in-xcode-8-swift-3/39516303#39516303

Comment: can you print `user`

Comment: @Mr.UB it dint solve my purpose

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - yes i able to

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let dataDict = user as? [String:AnyObject] {
    var email     = dataDict["email"] as? String
    let firstName = dataDict["first_name"] as? String
    let lastName  = dataDict["last_name"] as? String

    //self.nameLabel.text = "\(firstName!) \(lastName!)"

    var pictureUrl = ""

    if let picture = dataDict["picture"] as? [String:AnyObject], let data = picture["data"] as? [String:AnyObject], let url = data["url"] as? String {
        pictureUrl = url
    }
}
```

You need to convert the `user` type `Any` to type Dictionary `[String:AnyObject]`, then only you can use subscripts to extract value from it.

Comment: updated the code.

Comment: use of unresolved identifier dataDict in ' if let picture =dataDict["pic......'

Comment: I think you are missing brackets, the whole code should be within `if let` condition, there we have defined `dataDict`.

Comment: thank you so much for your help