# Type Any? has no subscript members on NSDictonary iOS

Tags: swift3

I am trying to change my code to swift 2.1 to swift 3

but I am getting following error :

```
Type Any? has no subscript members
```

Earlier I was using

```
let activityCount = self.activityCoutArray.value(forKey: "ActivitytodoCount")[0].value(forKey: "Count") as! Int
```

and I have changed to Swift 3

```
let activityCount = self.activityCoutArray["ActivitytodoCount"][0]["Count"] as? [String:Any]
```

but still it is giving same error ,

Please help me where I am going wrong..

Comment: In Swift 3 the compiler must know the actual type of all subscripted objects for type safety reasons. That kind of chaining is not supported (anymore).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'Any' Has no Subscript Members in xcode 8 Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516199/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-in-xcode-8-swift-3)

Comment: @user28434 My query here is different for swift not fir jquery

Comment: @RaghavChopra, doesn't matter which query you have, root problem is same, and is fixable in same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this. First get array of dictionary(`[[String:Any]]`) and then access the first element from array after that get the value from `Dictionary` that you want.

```
if let activityArray = self.activityCoutArray["ActivitytodoCount"] as? [[String:Any]],
   let firstDic = activityArray.first, let count = firstDic["count"] as? Int {
      print(count)
}
```

Comment: @RaghavChopra Welcome mate :)

Comment: Can you please me with this line let inboundCallCount = self.activityCoutArray.value(forKey: "InboundCallCount")![indexValue] as? String

Comment: @RaghavChopra Doesn't get your above comment what you want?

Comment: let inboundCallCount = self.activityCoutArray.value(forKey: "InboundCallCount")![indexValue] as? String

Comment: Not able to change the above line as well

Comment: @RaghavChopra It should be like this `if let array = self.activityCoutArray["InboundCallCount"] as? [String] {
       let inboundCallCount = array[indexValue]
}`

Comment: Thanks I m new to Swift 3 so bad with Syntax ,Really appreciated for help :) Hope to get help in future also

Comment: @RaghavChopra Please accept my answer if its works for you.

Comment: I have already doen that Please help me in future cases if any thanks for your response.

Comment: @RaghavChopra Sure, just put link of question here if possible will help you :)