# Converting error: Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Tags: swift, swift3

After converting the for loop to Swift 3 I got the error "Type 'Any' has no subscript members"

```
for inputKey in inputKeys where attributes[inputKey]?[kCIAttributeClass] == "NSNumber"
                                .....................^
{

}
```

I would expect to add something like

```
for inputKey in inputKeys where attributes[inputKey]as?[String:Any][kCIAttributeClass] == "NSNumber"
```

but this doesn't work :-(
Still have some problems with the Swift syntax.

Comment: Where / how is `attributes` defined? Basically the compiler must know the type of all subscripted objects.

Comment: Actually, `where` is still supported for `for in` loops.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'Any' Has no Subscript Members in xcode 8 Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516199/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-in-xcode-8-swift-3)

Comment: @JAL also AnyObject doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want `attributes` to actually be `[String: [String: String]]` - a dictionary of dictionaries.

Either that, or you can cast `attributes[inputKey]` to `[String:String]`.

I think this would work:

```
for inputKey in inputKeys where (attributes[inputKey] as? [String:String])?[kCIAttributeClass] == "NSNumber"
```

**Edit per comments:**

Since `attributes` isn't actually guaranteed to be `[String: [String: String]]`, but only `[String: [String: Any]]` (and maybe not even that), you'll need an extra `as?` cast to be safe.

With that many casts on one line, I think it would be better to put the test into a `guard` statement at the beginning of the `for` body instead of having such a huge `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what was needed :-)

Comment: While this will compile, it may not produce the expected results. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreimage/cifilter/1437661-attributes), the dictionaries in `attributes` will probably be of type `[String:Any]`.

Comment: In that case you may need to cast `attributes[inputKey]` to `[String:Any]`, and cast the result of the `[kCIAttributeClass]` subscript with `as? String`. With all that casting, it might be cleaner to use a `guard` statement at the beginning of the loop body instead of such a complex `where` clause.

Comment: You should probably add the comment as an edit to the original answer as the cast to [String:String] will fail most (if not all) of the time.

Comment: If it's set to [String:Any] and comparing to "NSNumber", you'll get the error "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'String'"