# type 'any' has no subscript members in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am getting this error at the line   `if let arrJson = allContacts["contacts"]`

in the below code:

```
if let arrJson = allContacts["contacts"]     {
            for index in 0...arrJson.count - 1
            {
                let aObject = arrJson[index] as! [String : AnyObject]

                names.append(aObject["name"] as! String)
                contacts.append(aObject["email"] as! String)

                }
            }
```

Please help me what to do?
I have tried this one but not solved this error [Type 'Any' Has no Subscript Members in xcode 8 Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516199/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-in-xcode-8-swift-3)

Comment: You havent declare type of `allContacts`, try `(allContacts as! [String : Any]).["contacts"]`

Comment: I suggest using some framework like SwiftyJSON for parsing json. Using pure swift for this is hell.

Comment: i am new to swift threfore i am just learning how to parse json data in swift @Makalele

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
let tempDic = allContacts as! Dictionary<String,Any>
        if let arrJson = tempDic["contacts"]      {

            let arrJson = arrJson as! Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>
            for index in 0...(arrJson).count - 1
            {
                let aObject = arrJson[index] as [String : AnyObject]

                names.append(aObject["name"] as! String)
                contacts.append(aObject["email"] as! String)

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error b'coz you `allContacts` not declared as Array, Dictionary or Set (these collection has subscripts).

So what you all need to do is to cast `allContacts` in appropriate type.

eg.

```
`allContacts as! Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>`
`allContacts as! Array<Any>`
```

Comment: JSON dictionaries have always `String` keys by definition. So it's  `Dictionary<String, Any>`

Comment: yeah, thats also true..