# Iterate through all keys of one child in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my structure in the Firebase Realtime database:

[image]

I want to get for all products the name.

Here's what I tried:

```
database.child("customerID").child("productTopSeller").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  for childSnap in snapshot.children.allObjects {
    let product = childSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot
    print(product.value?["name"] as? String ?? "")
  }
}) { (error) in
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

But this gives my following error:

```
Type 'Any' has no subscript members.
```

I know I would need to cast the snapshot somehow but couldn't figure out how to do this. using Swift 3.

Comment: Did you try googling the [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516199/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-in-xcode-8-swift-3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast `product.value` to `[String:Any]`. Look ad the following code

```
ref.child("customerID").child("productTopSeller").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
  let names = snapshot
      .children
      .flatMap { $0 as? FIRDataSnapshot }
      .flatMap { $0.value as? [String:Any] }
      .flatMap { $0["name"] as? String }

  print(names)    
})
```

> Please note I am using `observeSingleEvent` in order to get only one callback from Firebase.
>   Your code does use `observe` instead which produce a callback **every time** the observed data does change.